# Is it possible to open a JqModal pop-up iframe from flash

Tags: flash, jqmodal

I have a link in flash that I want to open with a JqModal popup.  I tried passing the string  in the flash varaible but that didn't work.

var flashvars = {
    testURL: "contact-us.html?q=jqmodal&go=&form=QBLH&width=781&height=400"
        };

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't very clear. From what I understood you want to open a JqModal dialog when a link is clicked inside a flash widget. Is that correct?
If it is you would probably have to use ActionScript to call a JavaScript function which will open the JqModal dialog.
I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the URL you mentioned.

Comment: yes, I have a link inside the flash which when the user clicks on it, it will open a jqModal iframe pop-up window.  I am not sure how to call the javascript frunction from the flash though.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This article tells you how to call a JavaScript function from inside Flash: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html